# PDF's stream seems imcomplete but rendered properly

Tags: pdf, stream

[image: table]

I made a 3x3 table that all cell is stroked but the outer lines are thick by Excel. Then exported to PDF and got the following stream (decoded from Flate).

```
q
49.56 728.5 169.25 60.12 re
W* n
 /P <</MCID 0>> BDC /GS6 gs
0 g
49.56 729.58 2.88 59.04 re
f*
0.14 w
/GS7 gs
0 G
 2 J  1 j
105.68 785.68 m
105.68 732.52 l
S
105.62 732.46 0.96 53.28 re
f*
```

I don't believe that this stream is complete to draw the table. Is something missed or a kind of interpolation working? Of course table is rendered properly on Acrobat Reader.

**The image is just to explain and is not what I made so its size differs.**

## Update

Please refer to the actual file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1We2jri-Y04fBYJcZ96HIs05DPeTSDOIc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is indeed not enough for drawing something like your image. Please share the pdf for analysis.

Comment: @mkl Added to the original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the content stream is a bit longer:

```
q
49.56 728.5 169.25 60.12 re
W*
n
/P <</MCID 0 >> BDC
/GS6 gs
0 g
49.56 729.58 2.88 59.04 re
f*
0.14 w
/GS7 gs
0 G
2 J
1 j
105.68 785.68 m
105.68 732.52 l
S
105.62 732.46 0.96 53.28 re
f*
160.76 785.68 m
160.76 732.52 l
S
160.7 732.46 0.96001 53.28 re
f*
214.85 729.58 2.88 56.16 re
f*
52.44 785.74 165.29 2.88 re
f*
52.5 768.76 m
214.79 768.76 l
S
52.44 767.86 162.41 0.96 re
f*
52.5 750.28 m
214.79 750.28 l
S
52.44 749.38 162.41 0.96 re
f*
52.44 729.58 165.29 2.88 re
f*
Q
EMC
```

All lines are drawn using filled narrow rectangles. The inner lines additionally are drawn as stroked single-edge paths. Those latter stroked paths are not necessary for the appearance.

You probably should check the code for FLATE decoding the content stream which returned you only a partial result.

Comment: I used [this code](https://gist.github.com/vortexau/13de5b6f9e46cf419f1540753c573206) to decode FLATE. And base64 to be passed is obtained by VSCode + hexdump, selecting a part of stream that indicated as `Length 250`.

Comment: Ahh my fault, it was a problem of [L10](https://gist.github.com/vortexau/13de5b6f9e46cf419f1540753c573206#file-decompress-ps1-L10) which quits loop when the line is blank even if it is not the eol. Thank you for your quick and elaborate explanation!

Comment: Indeed! One does not see that blank line in my dump but there is something like CR LF LF where your data stops...